# Analysing objects generated by a Java application in between GCs

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Is there a tool which could be used to analyse the objects being created **between two separate garbage collection run** (= number of objects created and their type) ?

Heapdumps dont really work here as they perform a GC when they're invoked (or at least that's what I observed everytime so far), and I want to see which objects are collected by the GC, not which objects are left after the GC run, if that makes sense.

Comment: For certain objects i override finalize method and add print statement that it is gc'ed.i find this useful when i suspect certain objects.certainly Not useful if there's many you are after.

Comment: do you mean which specific instances are collected & when or how many instances of each class are collected on specific GC events or something else? and which JVM? I am not aware of a way to do this with hotspot however ISTR jrockit (via command centre) reports on what is collected each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you always observe a full garbage collection before each heap dump, you probably called it like this:

```
jmap -histo:live $PID
```

If that's the case, just leave out the `:live`, which will suppress the explicit garbage collection.

In addition, the Sun JVM knows the following command line options:

```
-XX:+PrintClassHistogramBeforeFullGC -XX:+PrintClassHistogramAfterFullGC
```

That should be pretty much what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know which objects are collected by GC, the ['Unreachable objects histogram'](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/MemoryAnalyzer/FAQ#MAT_Does_Not_Show_the_Complete_Heap) from Eclipse Memory Analyzer may help.